# What's the most pythonic way to write this filtered list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Maybe i'm just up too late.

I have an object that is a thin wrapper around a dictionary. It will pretend to have a property for any key in the dictionary, and return None if a nonexistent key is referenced.

I want to get back only the unique, "truthy" values for three possible keys. (not None). the object may not have one or more of the keys. Or, it may have the same value in two or three of the keys.

This code does what I want:

```
set(getattr(obj, field) for field in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'] if getattr(obj, field))
```

I just don't like the look of repeating getattr() twice. I feel like i'm overlooking an obviously better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter out the `None` values afterwards:

```
set(filter(bool, [getattr(obj, field) for field in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']]))
```

Or you could just forget about the object. This is probably the way I would do it:

```
a_dict = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3missing': 3}

print set([a_dict[key] for key in ['key1','key2','key3'] if key in a_dict])

# prints: set([1, 2])
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the looks of this. will be back in the morning to tick a winner, upvoting these good answers for now.

Comment: Overall i like your style. The first one is what i was reaching for last night, but couldn't think of using bool as the filter. The second option is nice.

Answer (score 3):

If your thin wrapper returns default `None`:

```
s = set(getattr(obj, field) for field in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']) - {None}
```

another possibility:

```
s = set(filter(None, (getattr(obj, field) for field in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']))
```

Comment: You could do `- {None}` rather than `- set((None,))`.

Comment: Yah that's looking good for now. I also need to filter out '' but can add it to the subtracted set just as well.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, his thin wrapper already does the same as the default argument to `getattr`, so it's not needed -- `getattr` will return `None` for nonexisting attributes on his object.

Comment: good stuff, and the approach of subtracting {None, ''} seems to me to be more efficient as the field list gets longer. I need to learn more about internals to evaluate the tradeoff vs the filter approach. thanks for sharing this and i upvoted even though I didn't pick it.

Answer (score 3):

another take on using the getattr default:

```
set(x for x in getattr(obj, field, None) for field in ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'] if x)
```

**edit:**

here is to show you the logic behind this function - and to show why i think it might be better than some of the other solutions (i could be wrong - but hey - life is all about learning from mistakes)

```
obj = Your_Object
fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']

def get_set(obj, fields):
    result = []
    for field in fields:
        x = getattr(obj, field, None)
        if x:
            result.append(x)
    return set(result)
```

as you can see, there is only 1 loop, and `getattr()` is only called once for each field. and only "truthy" values are added to the result. i think this is a bit more efficient than getting all the results, and then removing the "non-truthy" values later. but please correct me if i am wrong. cheers.

Comment: this is cool, i need to learn more about the interpreter internals to understand whether this is better, worse or the same than my original code in terms of what actually executes. i'm still upvoting it though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
from operator import attrgetter

class DictWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.d)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.d.get(name)

    def truthy(self, *keys):
        values = attrgetter(*keys)(self)
        if not isinstance(values, tuple):
            values = (values,)
        return filter(None, set(values))

dw = DictWrapper({'x': 3, 'y': None, 'z': 'zebra'})
dw.truthy('x', 'y' ,'z', 'bob')
# [3, 'zebra']
dw.truthy('x')
# [3]
dw.truthy('y')
# []
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this, and it is a correct solution. I'm not a fan of adding a truthy message to my object though, because I don't need it elsewhere in the system, just this one place. but if i did need it all over the place, would do something like this.